# Re assigning pointers

Tags: pointers, arduino

I've got a bit of Arduino code that is driving me nuts at the moment and I'm hoping you helpful people can help.
What I want to do is initialise a pointer to one of two arrays of unsigned ints.
A switch is read each pass and the pointer is assigned accordingly, only the compiler has a hissy fit over the assignments.

```cpp
unsigned int spl_add_tbl[4096];   // arrary table no zero crossing points. 
unsigned int zxd_add_tbl[4096];   // array table for zero crossing points. 
unsigned int *tbl_ptr;  // init table pointer
  
// ZXD switch D64. H = off, L = on.
if (digitalRead(64) == 1) {
  // Zero Crossing off, assign Table Pointer to sample table
  *tbl_ptr = &spl_add_tbl[0]; 
} else {
  // Zero Crossing on, assign Table pointer to Zero Crossing Table and set A/D read mapping.
  *tbl_ptr = &zxd_add_tbl[0]; 
}
```

The compiler gives the error: invalid conversion from 'unsigned int*' to 'unsigned int' [-fpermissive]

Comment: `tbl_ptr` is a pointer to an `unsigned int`. `*tbl_ptr` is an `unsigned int`. Do not assign a pointer to an `unsigned int` to an `unsigned int`.

Comment: Cheers Eric, not sure I quite understand though.

Answer (score 0):

`tbl_ptr` is a pointer - you should not dereference it in order to assign an array to it:

```
if(digitalRead(64) == 1)
{
    // Zero Crossing off, assign Table Pointer to sample table
    tbl_ptr = &spl_add_tbl[0]; 
    
}
else 
{
    // Zero Crossing on, assign Table pointer to Zero Crossing Table and set A/D read mapping.
    tbl_ptr = &zxd_add_tbl[0]; 
}
```

Comment: Cheers Mureinik, that has done the trick and you've preserved my sanity. Can I just ask though, isn't the * the dereference ?.

Comment: @jlpniewski Damnit, dropped the quintessential word "not" there. Sorry, my bad. (the code itself shouldn't hasn't changed, though)

Comment: tbl_ptr = &zxd_add_tbl[0];    Could just be   tbl_ptr = zxd_add_tbl;  When you drop the brackets you have a pointer to the first element of an array.  No need to dereference with the brackets and then take address of again.